# How to perform 25519 ECDH with Hashicorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Vault's transit engine API doesn't seem to support ECDH against some of our stored keys?

I would imagine that would be available to pass in a pubKey against our key and do ECDH. Is that a design decision or is there a way to do it?

Comment: Good question...